# Timestamp field is not getting deserialized using Gson

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, amazon-sqs

I am trying to deserialize an SQS message whose message field is something like this:

```
{"Message":"{ObjectId:\"SomeObjectId:SomeVersion:1\",WorkId:\"12345abcdde\",Timestamp:2023-06-18T19:36:43.219Z,MsgFormatVer:1}"}
```

Basically I am able to get the String `Message` but I am not able to further deserialize.

These are the POJOs I am using to desrialize the message:

```
public class EventModel {
    private String Message;
}

public class SQSMessageBody {
    private String ObjectId;
}
```

This is the code:

```
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

public static <Message> Message getSQSMessage(final String message, final Class<Message> clazz) {
    EventModel eventModel = gson.fromJson(message, EventModel.class);
    return gson.fromJson(eventModel.getMessage(), clazz);
}

SQSMessageBody sqsMessageBody = getSQSMessage(message.getBody(), SQSMessageBody.class);
```

I don't need timestamp but it is not getting ignored. I also tried building the Gson builder like this:

```
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
            .create();
```

I am getting either of the below errors:

```
MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 137 path $.Timestamp
```

```
Unparseable date: "2023-06-18T19"
```

Note:

1. I cannot change the structure of SQS message.
2. I cannot add quotes to Timestamp value.
3. Without Timestamp field it works fine.

Comment: It looks to me like the problem is that the timestamp is not quoted, so the value of it gets terminated at the colon. Actually, in JSON the property names should be quoted as well, so even if the parser can handle some of that, it might be tough to parse a json of something that is not a valid json.

Comment: Hi @DanielBarbarian Thanks for your response. Yes I can also see the same but I cannot change the message structure at the source. Can we do something in our side? I don't need the Timestamp field. I am only intereseted in ObjectId.

Comment: If what you are trying to parse is not a valid json you can probably not rely on a json parser. The two options I see is that either you change the content of the data after it has arrived to make it into valid json or to write your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @DanielBarbarian wrote in the comments, the complete `Message` value is not valid JSON. None of the member names (e.g. `ObjectId`) are quoted, which is required by JSON. Gson just happens to accept this because it is [lenient by default](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#default-lenient).
But if possible you should not rely on this, because this "lenient mode" of Gson is not standardized in any way and allows all kind of malformed JSON. So if you were to switch to a different JSON library in the future, or tried to port the code to another programming language, you would run into issues.

The proper solution might be to find out how exactly this `Message` value is structured and if necessary write your own parser for it.